# What am I looking at here at Google Sky?

Tags: identify-this-object

I was looking through the Google Sky map, when [an object](https://www.google.com/sky/#latitude=43.91785094791645&longitude=-223.85801669893698&zoom=11&Spitzer=0.00&ChandraXO=0.00&Galex=0.00&IRAS=0.00&WMAP=0.00&Cassini=0.00&slide=1&mI=-1&oI=-1) caught my eye:

[image: Object at 43.91785094791645 latitude, -223.85801669893698 longitude]

I am really curious as to what this is (just a big star? then why does it look so peculiar?)

It's hard to search for online because I don't know which words to use. If anyone can point me in the right directon please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a star with pretty strong diffraction spikes.
To find out which one it is, you can just look up its coordinates in databases like [SIMBAD](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fcoo). 
Then you find that it is the star [Xi Cygni](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%4032161&Name=*%20ksi%20Cyg&submit=submit).
You can also find some information on it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_Cygni).

Comment: Looks more like a ton of false-color and possibly self-diffraction rings from circular aperture.

Comment: Following the SIMBAD link to the Aladin Lite view, [PanSTARRS/DR1](http://aladin.unistra.fr/AladinLite/?target=21%2004%2055.862%2B43%2055%2040.26&fov=0.59&survey=P%2FPanSTARRS%2FDR1%2Fcolor-z-zg-g) is a nice alternate. Google Sky looks like DSS2 + DSS2/blue.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thank you, learning about diffraction spikes is exactly what I was looking for without knowing what I was looking for.